# Is the SQLite row limit tested?

Tags: sqlite, rdbms

My friend and I had an argument about which relational database is better. It was totally opinionated, I prefer **MySQL** and he uses **SQLite**.
Then we checked the limits of these databases, and the row limit of SQLite was a ridiculously big number (2^64), and it got me thinking: did they actually test this?

Comment: See http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) says:

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2<sup>64</sup> (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.